# How can I get both Giga Drain and Mach Punch on Breloom?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I really want Breloom to know both Giga Drain and Mach Punch. Does Breloom learn Mach Punch on evolution or on level up only? In other words, do I specifically have to use a TM in order to obtain both on the first run-through or is it possible to use an Everstone to obtain Spore and Giga Drain, then remove the Everstone to evolve him and obtain Mach Punch on the evolution?

Comment: Breloom has a terrible special attack, so you may find that Giga Drain is not actually a very effective move for him.  Sadly, the lack of good physical grass moves in RSE makes Breloom less effective, since he can't make good use of his grass typing when attacking.

Comment: @conman In fact, there are *no* physical Grass moves in RSE (the physical/special split happened in Gen 4).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Oh yeah, that's right, which means that he is effectively bad at all grass moves.  I was thinking of later generations where he still effectively had the same problem, because they finally introduced physical moves, but his options were few.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Breloom_(Pok%C3%A9mon)/Generation_III_learnset):

In Generation III, Breloom can learn Mach Punch **only** by leveling up (at lvl. 23), so if you want to learn both Mach Punch and Spore, you must put Everstone on Shroomish and level him up to lvl. 54, learning Giga Drain at level 45, then you should let him evolve to Breloom and teach him Mach Punch through the Move Reminder.

Comment: Minor note: Everstone is optional, but it saves you the effort of having to cancel every attempted evolution until you learn Giga Drain (or Spore).

Answer (score 4):

[@Moondane suggested one method](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354363).

A second method is to obtain both a female Shroomish/Breloom and a breeding compatible male that know Giga Drain, such as Roselia or another Shroomish. [The Shroomish offspring will know Giga Drain](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Egg_Move). Then evolve the offspring into Breloom at level 23 to learn Mach Punch (or evolve later and use the Move Reminder). This also works with Spore instead of Giga Drain. This method is longer, but it does mean you can have a Breloom knowing both Spore and Mach Punch at level 50, which can be useful for the Battle Tower and/or Frontier.

[A third method is to clone a Pokemon holding TM19 (Giga Drain) on Pokemon Emerald.](https://www.wikihow.com/Clone-Pok%C3%A9mon-in-Emerald) This means you can teach Breloom Giga Drain with the TM and still have another TM19 afterwards. This is likely the fastest method provided you are using Emerald. This only works for TMable moves, which excludes Spore.

Comment: That third method makes me so grateful they made TMs multi-use.